# [Prestashop]: Code Changes in my address.tpl and errors.tpl. It doesn't updated Front-End

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I Changed in my **address.tpl** and **errors.tpl** file code is not updated Front-End Office.

I am not sure how this happened, but all of a sudden when I make some changes to **address.tpl**, it doesn't show in front -end.
For example,

I deleted   **{include file="$tpl_dir./errors.tpl"}**   line inside **address.tpl** file and saved the file but when I refresh my browser, no changes there.

Under

Preferences > **Performance**

Force compile: **yes**

Cache: **no**

I am not sure what is causing this problem.

Comment: Did you remove the compiled files from cache/smart/compile folder?

Comment: Are you sure to edit the file in the correct theme?

Answer (score 0):

You must be editing a wrong file or are expecting the changes in a wrong page. Try adding something and see if that appears in the source in front-end, if it doesn't then you are doing something wrong.

Moreover the line you are editing (i.e.  {include file="$tpl_dir./errors.tpl"}) effect the page only if there are some errors on the page you are expecting the changes.